# Problems after enabling Windows Defender Firewall

Tags: windows-server-2019

Problems after enabling Windows Defender Firewall.

Hello everyone!

After an update, the Windows Defender Firewall of my MS Server 2019 activated, since I can no longer access my server remotely, it will be over RDP as well as Remote Desktop.

Would anyone have any idea how to go about solving this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Slight nitpick: RDP is the Remote Desktop Protocol.

To solve the issue at hand I guess you would need console access to the server or VM. The simplest way of opening for RDP through the firewall is probably to turn off then re-enable the function in the server manager or computer properties. Doing that usually ensures all necessary settings are put in place in one go.
It’s also possible to manually enable the relevant remote desktop rules in the firewall directly.

To avoid having it happen again, I recommend never turning the firewall off in the first place: It’s good practice to know enough about what’s running on your servers to be able to selectively allow only wanted traffic through their firewalls; preferably with a limited range of allowed sources for anything but truly public traffic.

Comment: I understand, but after Fiewall has activated I can not access the server in any way. I really do not know what to do.

Comment: No, if that happened and the server is in a remote location with no support personnel available and no way of reaching its console (web console/ILO/IMM/BMC or networked KVM switch), it sounds like you’re in for some traveling.